# File Crashes when opened - how to Fix?

Tags: particles, system

I have been working on an animation recently, and in it is an object with a particle system. I set the particle emission to a rather high number (though by no means the highest I have ever done, about 100,000), cached it, and saved. I then went over to a second file for a few moments. Upon trying to return to my original, it, uh, kind of just crashes instead of opening.

This will not do.

I'm assuming it's the high particle count that's breaking the file, but now I can't get back in to lower it. I know I could probably just append in all objects but that into a new file or something, but I'd like to fix this file specifically, because that would be awesome.

Is there a way to re-open this file? If not, is there a way to edit the particle number without opening it in Blender itself?

(I'm using a 2018 MacBook Pro and Blender v2.81a)

Comment: It turns out the crash is being caused by a bug (reported, is currently on the developers' todo list), but the point of the question—that being how to alter a file without opening it in Blender itself—remains.